# Razor Editorfor and hiddenfor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

If you use `EditorFor()` and `HiddenFor()` property  for the same model in the view which one of their value gets sent to the action when submitted?

View

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.uname)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.uname)
```

Comment: Both of them send values if they're not disabled. The former shows in form where the latter is hidden (not to be seen), if they're taking same model the latter usually overrides the former value (but in terms of POST the former wins, and the latter is ignored).

Comment: Both are sent in the request, but only the first one is bound to your model in the POST method

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The first 1 that appears in the html will be sent.

Comment: @It'satrap, No, they are both sent

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah maybe. I crated a project and debugged and the first one was coming.

Comment: @It'satrap that's because of the `Model Binder`

Comment: I created a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mBSEP8. But what I see the sent value is the `HiddenFor` one... so I think the latter overrides former one.

Comment: @It'satrap - that's because the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first (and ignored the 2nd) - if you inspect the `Response` your will see both

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah in the response, both are coming. Thanks.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Apart from the fact your fiddle does not work, its using `$('#Uname').val()`which because of the invalid html will only ever select the first input

Comment: @StephenMuecke I fixed the fiddle and it shows inputted string in `EditorFor` now, so that the first helper bounds to the model binder.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, You script only sends one value (which is the first input), not both, so it does not show how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The first one that appear in the `view` will get while submiting to the controller.